# Two borders for panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I've done the following, but the problem that the entire panel double borders are not getting filled correctly. The right and down line for //Inner Border is not Painted.
The target control is **Panel**

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.Bounds);

        // Inner Border
        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(_InnerBorderColor.R, _InnerBorderColor.B, _InnerBorderColor.G), 1.0f), 1, 1, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.Bounds);

        // Main Border
        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(_BorderColor.R, _BorderColor.B, _BorderColor.G), 1.0f), 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
    }
```

This is What I got
[image]

This is What I need
[image]

**Edited**

Comment: I think it's better to post a picture and mark inner border and outer border on the picture. And by the way, Why you don't create pen simply this way? `new Pen(_OuterBorderColor, 1)`

Comment: @RezaAghaei -  Because I need Color.FromArgb Properties later on. I'll Post the Pic now with Edit

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Kindly check the posted pictures. Thanks in Advance

Comment: try -2 instead of -1. here `...ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1...`

Comment: @Emad-Developer I posted the fix for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this coordinates:

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen1, 
    this.ClientRectangle.Left, this.ClientRectangle.Top,
    this.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 1);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen2, 
    this.ClientRectangle.Left + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Top + 1,
    this.ClientRectangle.Width - 3, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 3);
```

Note:

- For outer rectangle, you should subtract -1 from original width and height to be visible
- To draw inner rectangle, you should draw from 1,1 so the width and height  will be 2 point less than outer width and height and since the outer width and height are original width and height -1, so you need subtract -3 from original width and height.

Comment: Really Thanks It is Working Now, I didn't think about Left and Top. I was trying to work with X and Y. Is there any difference between X,Y and Top,Left ?

Comment: @Emad-Developer You are welcome:) Left and X are equals, also Top and Y.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple bugs.  Using Bounds is wrong, that is in parent coordinates, use DisplayRectangle instead.  You draw the background twice, neither is necessary, the second one overpaints the inner rectangle.  You draw the inner rectangle two pixels too big.  You forget to dispose the pens, you tend to get away with it but very ugly bug to diagnose when you don't.  And last but not least, this should be done in OnPaintBackground so it doesn't flicker like a cheap motel.

Painting bugs are not that easy to diagnose, best way to go about it is incrementally, one piece at a time.

Corrected code looks like:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pe) {
    base.OnPaintBackground(pe);
    // Inner Border
    using (var pen = new Pen(_InnerBorderColor))
        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 1, 1, ClientSize.Width - 3, ClientSize.Height - 3);
    // Main Border
    using (var pen = new Pen(_BorderColor))
        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract 2 from Client.Width/Height

```
pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(_InnerBorderColor.R, _InnerBorderColor.B, _InnerBorderColor.G), 1.0f), 1, 1, ClientSize.Width - 2, ClientSize.Height - 2);
```

Comment: Alternative, deflate a rectangle by using `Rectangle.Inflate(-1, -1)`